# Debugging issues that work on one server, but not another?

Tags: debugging, iis

I have an asp.net application that works on the development server.  On the production server, it is failing though.  If I set the connection string in web.config to point to the production database, it still works, so does this mean that it is a server issue that is causing the problems and if so, what are some techniques for debugging this type of issue.  Also, what is the best way to debug intermittent session errors?  Is there some sort of session management in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

- permission settings
- config/environment settings
- expected installed apps
- dependencies
- firewall settings
- compare with development server & investigate the differences

The problem could be caused by a one or more of a wide set of things.
(Also maybe pop the question on SeverFault)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a good time to check the event logs and start testing your app in pieces.  (you do have layers right :)  You might also check to see if you have code access security turned of in your dev environment.

Their out stack traces or app logs there isn't much I can say that wasn't covered by [slashmais](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499671/debugging-issues-that-work-on-one-server-but-not-another/1499925#1499925)